# database updating but still throwing exception

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I am new to PHP OOP programming when I am trying to update my database using PHP it throws me this exception and query also run perfectly and database also updating. but still it's throws me this error

> Exception in /var/www/html/thaalinda/includes/querys.inc.php:8 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/thaalinda/includes/test.php(12): adminQuery->insertquery(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO ff(...') #1 {main}

This my database connection Code:

```
<?php 
class admindatabase{

  protected $host  = "localhost";
  protected $database = "testmy";
  protected $user  = "lkd";
  protected $pwd = "";
  public $connection;

public function connect(){
    $connection = new mysqli($this->host , $this->user , $this->pwd , $this->database);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("Connect error:%S\n",mysqli_connect_errno());
        exit();
    }
    else{
        return $connection;
    }
}

public function disconnect(ab $connection){
     $connection->close();
    }
}
?>
```

This is my query Class

```
    <?Php
 class adminQuery{

    public function insertquery($con , $query){
       try {
           $con->query($query);

        throw new Exception($con->error);

       } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
       }
    }
}


 ?>
```

This is my test PHP

```
    <?Php
require "./admindatabase.inc.php";
require "./querys.inc.php";


$myob = new admindatabase();

$connection = $myob->connect();

$query = new adminQuery();

$query->insertquery($connection,'INSERT INTO ff(ok) VALUES("Thaalinda BAndara")');
 ?>
```

Comment: I think you will always get an exception message printed out since you are manually throwing an exception with throw new Exception($conn->error)

Comment: Thak you for help your correct.  I had to put that manual exception in side a else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?Php
 class adminQuery{

    public function insertquery($con , $query){
       try {
           $con->query($query);

           throw new Exception($con->error);  // Here you're throwing the exception manually 

       } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
       }
    }
}
```

put it in a condition when $con->error.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. then how should I verify if the query run correctly or not?                                                                                   `If($con->query($query)){//}                                                             
           else{throw new Exception($con->error);}`                                 is this what are saying?